# Stop a Nginx Docker container

Tags: nginx, docker

I am trying to stop a Docker container running Nginx only after there has been no activity in the access.log of that Nginx instance for a period of time.

Is it possible to stop a Docker container from inside the container? The other solution I can think of is to have a cron running on the host OS that checks the `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/[container id]/` but I am planning on starting lots of containers and would prefer not to have to keep a list of IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docker container stops when the main process in the container stops.

I setup a little dockerfile and a start script to show how this could work in your case:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx
COPY start.sh /
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

**start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
nginx &
sleep 20
# replace sleep 20 with your test of inactivity 
nginx stop
```

**Build container, run and test**

```
$ docker build -t ng .

$ docker run -d ng 

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
3a373e721da7        ng:latest           "/start.sh"         4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        443/tcp, 80/tcp     distracted_colden   
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
3a373e721da7        ng:latest           "/start.sh"         16 seconds ago      Up 16 seconds       80/tcp, 443/tcp     distracted_colden   
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could share your docker sock within that docker image and then do any operations necessary.

to share docker sock within the docker image do something like this:
`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/bin/docker YOUR_IMAGE`

inside ENV vars you will have your container id, example to run within container `echo $HOSTNAME`

Answer (score 0):

I ran an nginx container and then wasn't able to fire it up again:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to unix:/var/run/nchan.sock failed (98: Address already in use)
```

The easiest fix was to just "prune":

```
docker system prune
```

Answer (score -1):

Docker can run command in your running container using the exec command:

```
 docker exec [-d|--detach[=false]] [--help] [-i|--interactive[=false]] [-t|--tty[=false]] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]
```